# Debugging Union Find Algorithm Implementation

Tags: python, data-structures, union-find

I'm attempting to solve LeetCode problem [547. Number of Provinces](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-provinces/description/):

> There are `n` cities. Some of them are connected, while some are not. If city `a` is connected directly with city `b`, and city `b` is connected directly with city `c`, then city `a` is connected indirectly with city `c`.
>
> A **province** is a group of directly or indirectly connected cities and no other cities outside of the group.
>
> You are given an `n x n` matrix `isConnected` where `isConnected[i][j] = 1` if the `ith` city and the `jth` city are directly connected, and `isConnected[i][j] = 0` otherwise.
>
> Return *the total number of **provinces***.

I tried to implement the union-find algorithm for this problem, but despite adding numerous debugging points, I'm still unable to identify the issue in my code.

#### Code:

```
class Solution(object):
    def findCircleNum(self, m):
        n = len(m)
        parent = [i for i in range(n)]
        rank = [1 for i in range(n)]
        count = n
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(i+1, n):
                if m[i][j] == 1:
                    p1, p2 = parent[i], parent[j]
                    if p1 != p2:
                        print(parent)
                        # print(rank)
                        count -= 1
                    r1, r2 = rank[p1], rank[p2]
                    if r1 >= r2:
                        parent[j] = p1
                        rank[p1] += 1
                    else:
                        parent[i] = p2
                        rank[p2] += 1
        return count
```

**Test Case:**

```
test_input = [[1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0],
              [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0],
              [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1],
              [0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1]]

print(Solution().findCircleNum(test_input))
```

The above code is returning `2` but expected is `3`

Could someone help me identify the problem in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

- the condition `p1 != p2` (which in your code means `parent[i] != parent[j]`) is not always a correct indication whether the nodes `i` and `j` are in a different set.  If `p1` and `p2` have a common ancestor via (potential multiple) `parent` dependencies, they still belong to the same set. An important step in Union-Find is to perform the *find* operation. There are several implementations possible, but this is one:

  ```
      def find(i):
          while i != parent[i]:
              parent[i] = parent[parent[i]]
              i = parent[i]
          return i
  ```

  and you should call it to make sure you reach the *root* of a parent-path:

  ```
  p1, p2 = find(i), find(j)
  ```
- A related error is in the union operation: `parent[i] = p2` may relink a node `i` that is not the root of the tree it is in, and so its ancestors will not be unified to the other tree. This should be `parent[p1] = p2`. A similar correction is needed in the alternative case.

Then there are two points that affect efficiency:

- The code that performs the union does not need to be executed when the nodes were already found to be in the same set, so you could move it inside the `if` block.
- The rank should only be incremented when the original two ranks were equal, as the rank represents the height of the tree.

Here is your code with these corrections applied (cf. comments):

```
class Solution(object):
    def findCircleNum(self, m):
        def find(i):  # The path-halving algorithm
            while i != parent[i]:
                parent[i] = parent[parent[i]]
                i = parent[i]
            return i

        n = len(m)
        parent = [i for i in range(n)]
        rank = [1 for i in range(n)]
        count = n
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(i+1, n):
                if m[i][j] == 1:
                    # Need to find the roots of the trees these nodes are in:
                    p1, p2 = find(i), find(j)
                    if p1 != p2:
                        count -= 1
                        # Only need to perform union when nodes were in different sets
                        r1, r2 = rank[p1], rank[p2]
                        if r1 >= r2:
                            parent[p2] = p1  # Attach one root to the other
                            if r1 == r2:  # No increment is needed if ranks are different
                                rank[p1] += 1
                        else:
                            parent[p1] = p2  # Attach one root to the other
                            # No increment is needed if ranks are different
        return count
```

Comment: I have selected the path-halving algorithm here -- it performs half the updates. There are different algorithms and they lead to the same time complexity (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#Finding_set_representatives)).